# Decide whether this is correct, using the method of resolution. If not, provide a counter example.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, formal-proofs

I am new to logic and wanted to decide whether the following is correct using the method of resolution: |= p → ¬ (p → (p ∧ (p ∨ q)))

My attempt to this I answered that the conclusion is incorrect, though the premises hold true. Thus, I begin with the negation of the conclusion and solve for validity.

```
                                   ¬ (p → ¬ (p→(p ∧(p ∨ q)))) ↔

                                   ¬ p ∧ ¬ (¬(p→(p ∧(p ∨ q)))) ↔

                                   ¬ p ∧ (p→( p→(p ∧(p ∨ q)))) ↔

                                   ¬ p ∧ (p→(p ∨ p)) ↔

                                   ¬ p ∧ (p→p) ↔ ¬ p ∨ p
```

Therefore, I deduced two clauses from the negated conclusion,  ← p  and p  ←

Resolution gives the clauses in one step.          ← p  and p  ←

Comment: Your method is not so clear to me... Having said that, the formula is **not** a tautology: check it with truth table (when $p$ is TRUE, the formula is FALSE). Thus, you cannot prove it (by Resolution or any other method).

Comment: @Mauro, Thanks for your thought. I am suprised that is the method used in solving similar questions in the textbook, hence, i am unsure with my answer. However, i have checked the truth table and the formula came out both false twice and true twice. I think it is a contingent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error is already in the first step. You simplified $\neg(a \rightarrow b)$ to $\neg a \wedge \neg b$ but it should be $\neg(\neg a \vee b) = a \wedge \neg b$.

$$\neg (p \rightarrow \neg  (p\rightarrow(p \wedge (p \vee q))))$$
$$p \wedge \neg\neg(p\rightarrow(p \wedge (p \vee q))))$$
$$p \wedge (p\rightarrow(p \wedge (p \vee q))))$$
$$p \wedge (p \vee q)$$
$$p$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your responsive correction. Is my comment " the conclusion is incorrect, though the premises hold true" still correct with your workings? Also my comment of "Therefore, I deduced two clauses from the negated conclusion, ← p and p ←

Resolution gives the clauses in one step. ← p and p ←" still correct?

Comment: @Harrisson I'm sorry, I'm afraid I don't understand.

Comment: @ Orlp. I mean the questions says that i should determine whether |= p → ¬ (p → (p ∧ (p ∨ q))) is correct. Then my answer is "No, the conclusion is incorrect, though the premises hold true". Then i showed proof, of which you have corrected. I am now asking whether my answer in quote is still correct.

Comment: @Harrisson Statements like that aren't correct or incorrect. They can be inconsistent, but this one isn't. But calling it 'correct' is not something I would do.

Comment: @ Orlp. Ok, so if it is inconsistent, does that mean that the conclusion is false but the premise is true?

Comment: @Harrisson I don't know what you mean with "premise" or "conclusion". You just gave a formula and I gave one that is equisatisfiable but simpler. That's all. The formula  you gave is satisfiable if and only if $p$ itself is.

Comment: Ok. Now, i just learned something helpful from you. Thank you very much for your help. It is well appreciated :) .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108637/discussion-between-harrisson-and-orlp).

Comment: @Harrisson Sorry I'm not interested in discussing this further. If something is unclear please make a new question.

Comment: Sorry that was a reflex action. I am just exploring the functions here. This is my first day. Your correction is very clear.